# Android studio 3.1 does not show link to compiler error

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

In new version on android studio I'm not getting link for compiler error and just getting a text, in old version everything well done, how to fix it? I singled out the text of error without link in Example:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the code at line: 162 in file LoginActivity.java?

Comment: @CaoMinhVu updated question

Comment: Instead of screenshot, you should post your error message, along with related codes in your questions. Edit your question please.

Answer (score 1):

Update

```
refresh.onTokenRefresh(manager);
```

to:

```
refresh.onTokenRefresh();
```

Comment: i dont want to fix this error. I want that my compiller show me link to this error

Comment: I am not sure AndroidStudio will link to error in this case since the error happens at compile time, not executing time. You can try to make a crash in the code to see whether Android Studio works correctly